# Angular2 component testing. Karma not loading templateUrl

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I am currently trying to write some tests for my Angular2 application and am having some issues whereas if I use the templateUrl property of the Angular2 component (linking to an HTML file) instead of template the test does not run. The async call back within the test will timeout as the .html file is not loaded. When I place the template code within the component file itself it works correctly. I can also see the request for the .html timing out in my browser so this leads me to the problem that the .html file is not being found.

I have looked at my karma.conf file and everything seems to be in order. I have also set this line to 'true' to include .html files when Karma is running in the karma.conf file:

```
{ pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: true, watched: true },
```

Here is my whole karma.conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

    var appBase    = 'app/';      // transpiled app JS and map files
    var appSrcBase = 'app/';      // app source TS files
    var appAssets  = 'app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

    // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
    var testingBase    = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
    var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
        ],

        client: {
            builtPaths: [appSrcBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },

        customLaunchers: {
            // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
            // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
            Chrome_travis_ci: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        },

        files: [
            // System.js for module loading
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

            // Polyfills
            'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
            'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

            // zone.js
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
            'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

            // RxJs
            { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            // Paths loaded via module imports:
            // Angular itself
            { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

            { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },
            'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

            // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
            { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },


            // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
            // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: true, watched: true },
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

            // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
            { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
            { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
        ],

        // Proxied base paths for loading assets
        proxies: {
            // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
            "/app/": appAssets
        },

        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {},
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

        port: 9879,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false
    })
}
```

I am not sure why these .html files are not being loaded so can anyone see why this is happening? I don't want to include the template code in each component as some of them are very large and my file structure has already compensated for separate view-file functionality.

The component (with the code that works commented out):

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'categories-component',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html',
    //template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
    moduleId: module.id
})

export class CategoriesComponent {
    public title:String = 'Categories';
}
```

the testing module:

```
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture, ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { CategoriesComponent } from "../../../../components/catalog/categories/CategoriesComponent";
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";

let comp:    CategoriesComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CategoriesComponent>;
let de:      DebugElement;
let el:      HTMLElement;

describe('Component: CategoriesComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ CategoriesComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should display original title', (done) => {
        TestBed.compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                done();
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoriesComponent);

                comp = fixture.componentInstance; // CategoriesComponent test instance

                // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
                de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
                el = de.nativeElement;

                expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

I also get this error in the Karma Runner when starting Karma:

```
07 12 2016 14:17:15.658:WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html (socket hang up)
```

I am adding these URLs to add extra clarity to my answer. When I access the application the successful XHR request for the template is:

```
http://product-admin.dev/app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html
```

And the URL that is being called to get the template from the test runner (and failing) is:

```
http://localhost:9879/app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html
```

the karma-test-shim file:

```
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

// builtPaths: root paths for output ("built") files
// get from karma.config.js, then prefix with '/base/' (default is 'app/')
var builtPaths = (__karma__.config.builtPaths || ['app/'])
    .map(function(p) { return '/base/'+p;});

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
    return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
    return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

// Is a "built" file if is JavaScript file in one of the "built" folders
function isBuiltFile(path) {
    return isJsFile(path) &&
        builtPaths.reduce(function(keep, bp) {
            return keep || (path.substr(0, bp.length) === bp);
        }, false);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
    .filter(isSpecFile)
    .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
    baseURL: 'base',
    // Extend usual application package list with test folder
    packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

    // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
    // Map the angular testing umd bundles
    map: {
        '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
    },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
    .then(importSystemJsExtras)
    .then(initTestBed)
    .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
    return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
        .catch(function(reason) {
            console.log(
                'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
            );
            console.log(reason);
        });
}

function initTestBed(){
    return Promise.all([
        System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
        System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
    ])

        .then(function (providers) {
            var coreTesting    = providers[0];
            var browserTesting = providers[1];

            coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
                browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
                browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
        })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
    return Promise.all(
        allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
            return System.import(moduleName);
        })
    )
        .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but it should be `included: false` for the html

Comment: I have added the URL's for the successful call and the call that fails from the spec runner to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Looking at the [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/karma.conf.js), it looks like this is where you go your karma config file from. Is your project based on the quickstart? I can clone it and try to reproduce the problem if that's the case.

Comment: I solved the issue if you look at my answer below. Do you have any idea why this has solved the issue as I am not quite sure why it has worked? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working but I don't understand how. I changed the appAssets variable to the following:

```
var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
```

I don't understand how this has worked as I'm not sure where the 'base' file exists as I can't see it in my file structure. It has worked though so if anyone would like to provide any further explanation that would be great.

Comment: I have think that might be coming from SystemJS config. If you look in the karma-test-shim, I think the the baseURL is set to `base`. I think that might have something to do with it, though I'm not completely sure. Sounds like it though.

Comment: It seems like you are correct. I have added the karma-test-shim file too. So that baseURL property in the SystemJS config just adds whatever value is in it to all requests?

Comment: I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Ok.I'll have a look into the documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I almost want to say that karma use 'base' as the base path for the server, and the SystemJS config is just using that. It makes a lot more sense to me than the SystemJS config setting the base path for the server

Comment: Okay, you are using absolute URL for the templateURL, and later mapping it in proxy inside karma.conf.js with '/app/': '/base/app/'; correct? if so that does fix my problem too, I just wanted to add a comment so that google picks up when someone searches, thanks :)